# Цикл For в Python

Tags: python

У меня есть код:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
file = f.readlines()
f.close()

x = input()

for i in file:
    if x in i:
        print(i)
    else:
        print('Об этом нету информации!')
```

И если в файле file.txt 5 строчек, то если условие не выполняется, строк "Об этом нету информации!" тоже 5 строк. Как сделать чтобы была только одна строка?

Comment: Причем здесь цикл?

Comment: For - цикл в Python

Comment: обратите внимание на отступы в конструкции `if ... else`

Comment: Спасибо, похоже при копировании получается не так как нужно

Comment: Перед циклом заведите переменную, в которой будет записано, есть информация или нет, в цикле измените её и в зависимости от её значения печатайте что нужно уже после цикла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
file = f.readlines()
f.close()

x = input()

count = 0
for i in file:
    if x in i:
        print(i)
        count += 1

if not count:
    print('Об этом нету информации!')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @НаильЯрулин, если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его как решение, нажав на галочку, или добавить ему балл, нажав на стрелочку вверх.

Answer (score 4):

Если задача кода только обнаружить факт наличия строки в файле, а не найти все вхождения, то можно обойтись и без переменной:

```
x = input()
with open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if x in line:
            print(line)
            break
    else:
        print('Об этом нету информации!')
```

Или ещё короче

```
x = input()
with open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    print(next((i for i in fh if x in i), 'Об этом нету информации!'))
```

А можно и все вхождения вывести

```
print(''.join(i for i in fh if x in i) or 'Об этом нету информации!')
```